# What is the equivalent of GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes in ASP.NET Core (.NET 5)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am migrating an ASP.NET MVC(.NET Framework 4.7.2) application to ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET 5) and have come across the following code: -

`tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata));`

How do I achieve the same as htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes in ASP.NET Core when using .NET 5?

Answer (score -1):

ASP.NET Core MVC offers a number of choices for various helper extension / addition scenarios. My recommendations：

If you want to change what a helper e.g. @Html.TextBox() does, subclass DefaultHtmlGenerator and override the relevant method(s) e.g. GenerateTextBox() or the lower-level GenerateInput().

If you want to add a very simple tag helper i.e. one that depends only on what IHtmlHelper exposes, write an IHtmlHelper or IHtmlHelper extension method.

If you want to add an unrelated helper, create a new class and place that type in DI. Then use @inject to include a property of the new type in your .cshtml files. (Probably need the class to implement IViewContextAware and its DI registration to be transient.)

The above avoids the service locator pattern. But feel free to use that pattern if the architectural and (likely) performance downsides are  in your application.